# Как сделать простое клиент серверное приложение на Android?

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком направлении работать для создания простого клиент серверного приложения такого плана: на сервере хранится набор файлов, который при необходимости загружается на мобильное устройство. Если загрузка выполнена, в дальнейшем должно проходить сопоставление количества файлов на устройстве и на сервере. При наличии расхождений производится синхронизация файлов на устройстве. То есть подгружаются или удаляются файлы. На устройстве должны быть всегда самые последние файлы. 
Если же отсутствует соединение с интернетом или изменений нет, то мобильное устройство работает с локальными файлами. 
Реализацию планирую на java

Comment: Начните с определения интерфейса (контракта) между клиентом и сервером.

Comment: у меня уже есть прототип этого приложения, там сделал так: на сервере лежат файлы и json файл. При запуске проверяется json и из него считываются данные по списку файлов. После этого происходит сравнение количества файлов в приложении и на сервере. Если отличается - происходит загрузка недостающих

Comment: В принципе это работает, но есть ряд недостатков: 1) не отслеживается идентичность файлов 2) нет возможности замены файлов на сервере и автоматической перезаписи их в приложении

Comment: Отлично, теперь замените статический json на сервере REST ресурсом, который бы отдавал вам то же самое, только сгенерированное на лету по списку файлов на сервере. Потом в него добавьте таймстемпы для файлов (или еще чего) чтобы определять "свежесть" файла. Потом уже можно будет говорить о загрузке файлов с клиента.

Comment: А как сделать такой REST ресурс? Есть какие то примеры?

Comment: Задайте вопрос про REST, вам подскажут.